# Javascript stops executing rest of the OR

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This is just a simple JavaScript form-validation that i put together, all the document.form.*.value exist on my page, except for the **document.form.dasdasdas.value ==''**

In the following code, with the point of it being to give an error if any of the forms are empty, in this case however, because i assume dasdasdas is not a form on my page, it doesn't, and my question is why.

Even though it doesn't exist, doesn't that make it empty?

My question is: Why does, after i filled everything in ( customername to customerpostcode ) and leave customerbank and customercity empty, it still says everything is oke ?

After deleting that line everything works just fine, but i'm curious to why it behaves like this!

An answer to this, not so good explanation would be, awesome!

Here is my code.

```
function FileChecked()
{
    if( document.form.customername.value =='' || 
        document.form.customerpassword.value =='' || 
        document.form.customerphone.value =='' || 
        document.form.customeremail.value =='' || 
        document.form.customeradres.value =='' || 
        document.form.customerpostcode.value =='' ||
        document.form.dasdasdas.value =='' || 
        document.form.customerbank.value =='' || 
        document.form.customercity.value =='')
            {
                alert('Not all forms are filled.');
                return false;
            }
    // Check if file is selected and extension is .csv
    if(document.form.csvfile.value =='')
        {
            alert('No file given');
            return false;
        }
    else
        {
        ext = document.form.csvfile.value.toLowerCase();
        if(ext.substr(ext.length-4) == '.csv')
            {
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            alert ('Filetype is not .csv');
            return false;
            }           
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `document.form.dasdasdas` doesn't exist, then it's `undefined`. You can't get the property `value` of `undefined` - hence the error.

You'd want to do something like

```
... || (document.form.dasdasdas === undefined || document.form.dasdasdas.value == '') || ...
```

but like i said, if `document.form.dasdasdas` doesn't exist on the `DOM` then it'll be pretty hard for someone to fill it in.

Comment: +1 ( if i could )Thanks for commenting, this makes absolutely complete sense, my assumption was that it would be empty, but it's undefined, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you try to get the value property of an element then it should be exist on the page or in `DOM` itself.

```
document.form.dasdasdas
```

I believe here you are trying to get a value of an non existing element so when you are trying to get it's value property it gives you `undefined`.

To avoid this first you need to check this for undefined and then get it's value and do your comparision

```
(document.form.dasdasdas != undefined || document.form.dasdasdas.value == '')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it makes sense to me now.